# Primary Key / Foreign Key naming convention in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys, naming-conventions, primary-key

There are some kind of different approaches regarding to `Primary Key` and `Foreign Key` naming conventions in `MVC` and I would like to be clarified about which one is most likely close to the standard convention even if there is almost no difference between them. Here is an example code below using two tables called `Student` and `Country`.

**Convention I:** I would prefer this approach as I do not want to repeat the table names on each `PK` property.

*Student Table*

```
ID => Primary Key property
CountryId => Foreign Key property
```

*Country Table*

```
ID => Primary Key property
// other properties
```

**Convention II:**

*Student Table*

```
StudentId => Primary Key property
CountryId => Foreign Key property
```

*Country Table*

```
CountryId => Primary Key property
// other properties
```

In addition to this issue I also want to know that if there is a difference using `ID` or `Id` as `Primary Key` in an `Entity Class`. Any idea?

Comment: What is wrong with: `PK_StudentId` and `FK_CountryId` ?

Comment: It is a nice answer indeed...mine was just a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is destined to be closed as opinionated, but I'd go with the first convention. It's more of a pet peeve of mine than anything, but it bugs me to no end when I see stuff like:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Well, *of course*, it's the student's id and the student's name. That's the name of the class. Then, your API looks like `student.StudentName`, which just reads ridiculously.

Long and short, if the property is intrinsic to the class, do not prefix it with the class name. You should have an API like `student.Id` and `student.Name`.

When it comes to foreign keys, you *should* prefix it with the class name because that tells you about the relationship. Something like `student.CountryId` very clearly indicates that this is the foreign key for a student's country. In programming, readability and self-documenting APIs are paramount.

Comment: What about the ID vs Id part? Which one is better?

Comment: I go with `Id`, simply because I think it follows the pascal-casing more appropriately. That one's a bit of a wash, though. `ID` is obviously an abbreviation of `Identifier`, and if you were to use the whole word it would be `CountryIdentifier`, not `CountryIDENTIFIER`. However, `ID`, even though it is not an acryonym, is treated like an acronym many times. It really boils down to the same argument between using something like `HTMLClass` or `HtmlClass`. ASP.NET tends to prefer the latter form, so I follow that convention with `Id` as well.